# How to add checklist on my notes app in the writing area

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, web-applications

So, I am making a note taking app with react, and I want to make something that works like apple notes where you can click on the checkbox and it adds a new checkbox to the writing area.It keeps adding a new one when you press return/enter until you press backspace, and then you can resume typing regular text. I've been trying to do it yesterday pretty much the whole day, I found some rich editor text libraries but even though they have functionality to style the text e.g bold, italic etc. I cannot find a library that provides this specific functionality. I tried using a div with the contentEditable attribute instead of textarea but I wasn't sure what to do.

[In case my explanation was bad here is an image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlT1i.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.